# Integrate ParticlesJs into a view component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, particles.js

I want to integrate ParticlesJs into my landing page. So only my home view should use this particles configuration and render particles.

I created a snippet and added the ParticlesJs dependencies

https://codesandbox.io/s/ol2rnrlxxq

Two problems come up:

- I added the ParticlesJs file to the sandbox but the function `particlesJS` is not defined
- I still want to have the content wrapped by `v-layout` in the center of the screen. How can I keep it? I wrapped the view with `v-content` because I think I have to add `<div id="particles-js"></div>` on top level of the component

The final result should look like this.

[image]

I added the `flat` attribute to the card so fixing the two problems should make it work.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://vue-particles.netlify.com). Is probably the easiest way to integrate in a vue project.

Comment: Well I think your answer needs an upvote too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your `particlesJS` initialize code in `mounted` hook instead of `created`. Because in `created` hook, DOM elements does not created yet. Please see more about [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted).

```
export default {
  mounted () {
    particlesJS("particles-js", {
      ...
    })
  }
}
```

To make `particles-js` fullscreen:

```
#particles-js {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

To make your layout center (from [Layout grid system example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid#examples)):

```
<v-layout align-center justify-center row fill-height/>
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/00q2kkr4jl)